# If it was or if it were or if it is

Tags: american-english, british-english

My friend wrote a status like this

```
Working on read-only environment makes you couldn't do anything. You can only get notice and warning. We are required to obey and submit to the circumstances
```

should i comment ," If it is writeable environment ... " or "If it were writeable environment..." ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it [is/was] **a** writable environment...

If [they] [were] writable environment[s]...

The word choice depends on the tense of the sentence for *is/was* and requires the use of the article (*a*). 'It' becomes *they* and 'was' becomes *were* when working with the plural of "environment". Given the grammar in that status report, I wouldn't be worried either way.

-[Article, grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29)

-[WasOrWere.com](http://wasorwere.com/)